# What is shared tags / Simple tags for docker images

Tags: docker

What is Shared and Simple tags for Docker images?

Why is it in place ?
I could see shared/simple tags for

https://hub.docker.com/_/hello-world

A detailed explanation would help me.

Comment: [What's the difference between "Shared" and "Simple" tags?](https://github.com/docker-library/faq#whats-the-difference-between-shared-and-simple-tags)

Answer (score 0):

From 
[docker library, mongo](https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/issues/316)

in short, "...(images) *are identified by simple tags. Simple tags are like main tags. Shared tags group images together under common name*"

To my understanding, you can have multiple images having shared tag which I'd view as version (following mongo example):

```
3.2.21-jessie
3.2.21-windowsservercore-ltsc2016
3.2.21-windowsservercore-1709
```

would make it possible to pull 3.2.21 shared tag and have the correct exact image pulled form the registry based on the host running.